# unable to configure vsftpd using ssl

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

i am trying to setup vsftpd over ssl . followings are configuration under vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES
#idle_session_timeout=600
#data_connection_timeout=120
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#async_abor_enable=YES
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#deny_email_enable=YES
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
```

after setting up service is running properly but when i try to connect using filezilla i got some errors. iptables is stop working locally.
error -

```
Error:  GnuTLS error -50 in gnutls_priority_set_direct: The request is invalid.
Error:  Failed to initialize TLS.
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

my moto is to do so to avoid plain text authentication

i dont know where i am wrong please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Use another client. This is [a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1029485) in the Filezilla client.

Comment: i used ftp client with linux console & gftp then also getting regarding ssl